# Custom SelectionMode for GridView. Select only on right click

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to implement a bit complicated selection behavior for GridView in my Windows 8 app. I know that it is be possible as OneNote app from Windows Store implements exact same behavior as I want. Here is the behavior I want:

- If I left click on the item, only ItemTapped event should be triggered. Item should not be selected. This is exactly like `SelectionMode="None"`. Same behavior is expected when an item is tapped on a touchscreen device.
- If I right click, I should be able to select multiple items - just like `SelectionMode="Multiple"`. Similar thing should happen when user selects an item by swiping and pulling it a bit. If I left click an item again, all selected items should be unselected and ItemTapped should trigger.

In short, left click and item tap should behave as `SelectionMode="None"` while right click and swipe selection should work as `SelectionMode="Multiple"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want by first enabling multiple selection, as well as enabling the swipe gesture. Then on left click (in the tapped handler), you can de-select all items in code.

Xaml GridView options - this allows right-click and touch (swipe) selection:

```
SelectionMode="Multiple"
IsSwipeEnabled="True"
Tapped="itemGridView_Tapped"
```

Here is the code behind for the tapped event - on a left-click or tap, this deselects any selected items:

```
private void itemGridView_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while (itemGridView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        itemGridView.SelectedItems.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: I have `GridView` embedded inside another `GridView`. (Yeah, I know similar effect can be achieved using grouped `GridView` but I had some drag and drop to do!) So, I had to identify the `GridView` by doing 'sender as GridView`. It works! Your rock!

Comment: Why did you use a while loop to remove the selected items instead of the `ICollection<T>.Clear` method?

Comment: @Stefan no specific reason, what you suggested would work as well.